# Использование 'объектов' отображаемых на .jsp странице в JavaScript e

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

В `GovernmentController` был добавлен лист объектов для отображения на view `government.jsp`.

```
List<BankGovernment> bankGovernments = bankService.getAll();

GovernmentWrapper governmentWrapper = new GovernmentWrapper();
modelAndView.addObject("governmentWrapper", governmentWrapper);
governmentWrapper.setBankGovernments(bankGovernments);
```

Таблица с данными успешно отображается, используется `DataTables` и `bootstrap`.
На странице используется определение типа класса и в зависимости от него отображается одна или другая таблица с данными.

Есть статическая форма добавления нового 'row' для каждого из типов. 
Нужно добавить функционал редактирования, при этом как мне кажется, будет правильно использовать существующую форму для добавления и добавить в нее функционал редактирования.

При нажатии кнопочки `Edit` данные из таблице должны отобразиться в форме редактирования. Каким способом это лучше сделать?

**1.** возможно ли получение списка `bankGovernments` в js аналогично view?

```
c:forEach items="${governmentWrapper.carProducers}"
```

**2.** или нужно использовать прямой доступ к филдам получать их `value` и сетить в соответствующие поля формы для редактирования?

```
//Get

var bla = $('#txt_name').val();

//Set

$('#txt_name').val('bla');
```

---

Какой практичней способ использовать для заполнения формы значениями, которые уже отображаются на view? Как правильней добиться результата?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы передать значения из таблицы в форму для редактирование использовал js, тоесть брал значения из соответствующих филдов строки и сетил в соостветствующие филды формы вручную.

Да это не так элегантно как хотелось, лучше, на мой взгляд, было пройтись по `List<MyModel>` в js, сравнить по `id`, и получить соответствующие значения из модели, но я наткнулся на проблему:

При получении значения в js

```
function findAndFillEditForm(){
    var allModels = '${myEntitiesName}';    //возвращает Object@2547892347
}
```

возвращает адресс объекта в памяти, и прикастить его к реальному List не получилось, если есть рабочий вариант как это сделать, выложите плз)).

Поэтому рабочий вариант, вполне устраивает, просто немного больше кода пришлось написать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Манипулировать типизированной коллекцией в JS, насколько я знаю нельзя.
2. При нажатии на кнопку Edit можно загрузить ее через Ajax передав в
   параметре - (id) редактируемого элемента, на сервере получить данные
   по id и передать на клиент. 
    Далее в значении полей нужно
   поставить атрибут value="${item.filedName}"